# Execuring powershell commands from Java

Tags: java, powershell

I am trying to execute powershell commands from Java and have tried multiple options.

Commands that I want to try -

```
$SecureFilePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "<PFXPassword>" -AsPlainText -Force

$userPFXObject = New-IntuneUserPfxCertificate -PathToPfxFile "<FullPathPFXToCert>" -PfxPassword     $SecureFilePassword -UPN "<UserUPN>" -ProviderName "<ProviderName>" -KeyName "<KeyName>" -IntendedPurpose "<IntendedPurpose>"
```

I tried using ProcessBuilder to execute these - but i am not able to maintain session and hence it starts saying cmdlet not known even after importing the corresponding ps1 file.

Then I started with using jPowershell - here everything works fine except the above commands when it tries to use the set value inside $SecureFilePassword inside the next command - it fails saying "Not Specified"

Not sure if I am formulating the command properly to be executed - could some one help me?

Thanks
Sri

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and add Java code too.

Comment: In other words, please [edit] your question to add a [mre] demonstrating the problem; see [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a PowerShell script in a file that could be run in your shell as a single command and after that use ProcessBuilder.start() or Runtime.exec() method to run an external command from Java. See class [Process API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) for details